# Table row highlight + tooltip with image

Tags: jquery, html-table, tooltip, highlight

I'm trying to write a script that will

1. highlight table row and
2. show me tooltip with image whenever I'm on that row

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr class="thumbnail-item">
        <td class="column-1">1</td>
        <td class="column-2">2</td>
        <td class="column-3">3</td>
        <td class="column-4">4</td>
        <div class="tiptip"><img src="img.jpg" alt=""/></div>

    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('.thumbnail-item').mouseenter(function(e) {

  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;

  $(this).css('z-index','15')
  $(this).css('background', '#800000')
  $(this).css('color', '#ffffff')
  $(this).css('cursor', 'default')
  $(this).children(".tiptip").css({'top': y,'left': x,'display':'block'});


 }).mousemove(function(e) {

  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;

  $(this).children(".tiptip").css({'top': y,'left': x});

 }).mouseleave(function() {

  $(this).css('z-index','1')
  $(this).css('background', 'none')
  $(this).css('color', '#000000')
  $(this).children(".tiptip").animate({"opacity": "hide"}, 0);
 });

});

CSS

.tiptip
{
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

.thumbnail-item
{
position: relative;
}
```

Image somehow couldn't be shown. Will `children()` not select elements if they are hidden?

Comment: Just a side note, Your tooltips may not work to well on ajax applications as there is no tooltip remove on click

Comment: Will children() not select elements if they are hidden? It should still find the children no problem

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a `div` is not a valid child of a `table` element, this may not have a huge effect but valid xhtml seems to make jQuery work more smoothly (albeit that's entirely based on personal observation, which is hardly scientific).

Answer (score 1):

You can only have table cells (`<td>`,`<th>`) in a table row (`<tr>`).
*reference*: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5

So use a cell and put your div in there, and use the `.find()` method to target it.

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/egrMp/1

Comment: that works great, but if you put like 20 table rows and run in it in opera, every next row takes like + 10 px to tooltip vertically. whats with this?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to put a div element (block item) inside a table row.

All jQuery selectors select all elements, whether they are hidden or not.

Comment: ok whatever if i put image without <div> just with class .tiptip it doesnt work eiter...

Comment: You aren't allowed to put an image either. You need to use a cell (td) and put the image in it.